# Excel abnormally auto format my record from "xxxx/yy/zz" to "zz/yy/xxxx"

Tags: excel, vba

I debug in code, and I see that the value is in correct format, it just get and set the value only, and it seem like excel take the data as datetime instead of normal string,
I try to use NumberFormat and format it to either 1 of this (@, text, number, general) neither 1 is working, any help will be great

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = arr(i, 4)
```

**Update 1**
  Sorry to not mention arr, arr is multi dimension array, it store the column that I read from , I just get the value from excel, and the store in range by looping

Comment: What is `arr`, and what is `arr(1, 4)`? It seems like that would be important information to include in your question. Perhaps you should [edit] and add it so we have an idea what you're asking. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Value = "'" & arr(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, although it look stupid

I change the format to

```
.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

and I get the value I want

Comment: You didn't mention it was dates... You were formatting it as text as mentioned in your question and hence I gave you a solution with respect to that... Did you even try my solution?

Comment: it is never a date, is a text, but format it with date worked well, ur method also work, and I mark your as answer, just pointing out alternative :)